# What does "$\prec$" mean, as in $g(x)\prec e^{-x^2/2}$?

Tags: probability, notation, asymptotics

[image]

I just had a question regarding mathematical notation. I have never seen this "$\prec$" symbol before. Does it just mean $g(x)$ is less than the function?

Thank you!

Comment: Clearly what the need here is  the fact that $g(z)e^{z^{2}/2} \to 0$ as $|z| \to \infty$.  Since you have not told us what $g$ is it is difficult to say anything more.

Comment: Cf. [Hardy's asymptotic notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#History_(Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau,_Hardy,_and_Vinogradov_notations))